# Aeroplane Noise Reduction

Tags: noise, reduction

Does anyone have any advice on how to remove and aeroplane flyby? Ive tried with notched eq, but as the sound is dynamic it doesnt work. Im toying with getting RX 3 and was wondering if anyone has any cheaper solutions?

thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

First of all I don't think there's an easy solution to these kinds of noises.
Although RX3 is great product, it's not a magic pill (nor any other product.
It totally depends on how loud/continuous/'wide' it is. Since this is a flyby
it could mean that the sound evolves dramatically over the course of a few seconds.
This is much harder to reduce (with any technique).
Another thing: what does is it have to be reduced to relatively? Speech or is it
a natural soundscape? High pitched birdsong could 'survive' a hipass filter. Or you
could replace the airplane frequency range with another ambience of the same range
that doesn't have a lot of noises.

Anyway this is all stuff that takes a lot of time and effort, don't expect a perfect
soundscape afterwards.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Airplane ? - No Chance ;( Go and record again. Maybe this saves your time instead figuring out RX and realizing, this doesn´t work. I tried several hours to eliminate Airplane pass bys, but it never leads to pleasing results

Answer (score 1):

One thing to mention. Does the aeroplane really disturb, or does it only disturb you?

Ask another person to check that. Sometimes you get mad on things that are actually no problem at all. And make sure that the aeroplane is not vanishing in a cut or fade.

Comment: Yep ! Nothing more to say. We´re totally fixed on something that disturbes us. And sometimes it´s really not a real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Nah, iZotope RX is surely your best best.

It's such a broadband noise that it cannot be trivially removed. Either you'll cut an audible hole in the overall sound or you cannot damp the airplane sound enough, so it'll stay audible.

RX might just be able to cut it out and mask it with the "replace audio" features it has (by either copypasting another audio segment in place of the removed flyby sound or by having RX try synthesize the audio that's missing).

Without RX, you could also try cutting the entire flyby segment off and then try cross-fading the remaining segments to combine them back to a constant track. Or finding a segment that can fill the missing part. This can work if the track is an ambience track and is constant enough.

Answer (score 0):

Finding another (alt) take for those lines would be your best bet if that's something you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try cheating the sound from a different take that doesn't have the airplane. Or use ADR. Or live with the airplane. The RX3 tool is as good as you will find, but it can only reduce, not eliminate unwanted sounds.

Good luck.